# express.js req.body is always empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm learning node.js and express.js, and when I post something I have an empty body.

What I do is trying to get input from a registration form.
My app.js is (the relevant part):

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');


var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


// Handle Express session
app.use(session({
  secret:'secret',
  saveUnintialized: true,
  resave: true
}));
```

users.js is:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// Add model for user.
// Note that variable has first uppercase, and model name is singular.
var User = require('../models/user');

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

router.get('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('register', {
    'title': 'Register'
  });
});

router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login', {
    'title': 'Login'
  });
});

router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  // These values come from the form.control name in register.jade
  console.log('Register clicked...');
  console.log('Body: ', req.body);

});

module.exports = router;
```

and register.jade is:

```
extends layout

block content
  h1 Register
  p Please register using the form below
  ul.errors
        if errors
                each error, i in errors
                    li.alert.alert-danger #{error.msg}
  form(method='post', action='/users/register', enctype='multipart/form-data')
      .form-group
          label Name
          input.form-control(name='name', type='text', placeholder='Enter Name')
      .form-group
          label Email
          input.form-control(name='email', type='text', placeholder='Enter Email')
      .form-group
          label Username
          input.form-control(name='username', type='text', placeholder='Enter Username')
      .form-group
          label Password
          input.form-control(name='password', type='password', placeholder='Enter password')
      .form-group
          label Confirm Password
          input.form-control(name='password2', type='password', placeholder='Confirm password')
      .form-group
          label Profile Image
          input.form-control(name='profileimage', type='file')
      input.btn.btn-default(name='submit', type='submit', value='Register')
```

What's wrong????? I'm getting crazy :-(

Thanks

Comment: please add the part where you add the users route in app.js

Comment: var users = require('./routes/users');

Comment: this is where you require it, but you don't do anything with `users` in the code you provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be `app.use('/users', users);` somewhere in your app.js, make sure this is **after** your `app.use(bodyParser` block since body parsers will populate `req.body`.

You should also remove `enctype='multipart/form-data'` if you don't need file uploads or use the multipart parser in users.js:

```
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });
router.post('/register', upload, function(req, res) {
```

Comment: I have it: after app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); I have app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

Comment: Yup, should remove the file encoding because you are sending a JSON, not a file

Comment: @Sandman42: no, it's totally fine, I forgot to add `@nem:` to my last comment, who mentioned that there is no file upload.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in app.js:

```
var routes = require('./routes')
app.use(routes)
```

Comment: Could you explain what this code does, where to put it, and link to the relevant documentation (if it exists)? Please [edit] it into your answer.